# Creating a histogram for each value in multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a small section from my pandas dataframe. I would like to be able to get separate 'vel_x' histograms (counts, bins) for each value in count. Is there a fast, built-in way to do this without just looping through each value in count?

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+----+--------+
|       |       | x_loc | y_loc | vel_x  | …  |  vel_z |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+----+--------+
| count | slice |       |       |        |    |        |
|   1   | 3     |     4 |     0 |     96 | 88 |     35 |
|       | 4     |    10 |     2 |     54 | 42 |     37 |
|       | 5     |     9 |    32 |      8 | 70 |     34 |
|       | 6     |    36 |    89 |     69 | 46 |     78 |
|   2   | 5     |    17 |    41 |     48 | 45 |     71 |
|       | 6     |    50 |    66 |     82 | 72 |     59 |
|       | 7     |    14 |    24 |     55 | 20 |     89 |
|       | 8     |    76 |    36 |     13 | 14 |     21 |
|   3   | 5     |    97 |    19 |     41 | 61 |     72 |
|       | 6     |    22 |     4 |     56 | 82 |     15 |
|       | 7     |    17 |    57 |     30 | 63 |     88 |
|       | 8     |    83 |    43 |     35 |  8 |      4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+----+--------+
```

I have tried many methods (apply, map, etc.), but I have not been able to get any of them to work. Each method just applies the mapped function to all the row values.

Essentially, I want to map this to each value in count (count_value) below:

```
def create_histogram(data, count_value):
    values, bin_edges = np.histogram(data.loc[count_value, 'vel_x'])
    return values
```

then something like this:

```
data.index.get_level_values('Count').map(create_histrogram(data))
```

Also, for reference, this is the way I can currently perform what I want, but it is not very efficient because my dataframe is very large.

```
for count_value in data.index.get_level_values('Count').unique:
    values, bin_edges = np.histogram(data.loc[count_value, 'vel_x'])
```

the returned values can then be stored in another array.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post the [minimum, complete & verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code of one of the methods that you have tried?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have posted the code now. I did not feel like the code itself would be very helpful in this case because it is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `level` param:

> level : int, level name, or sequence of such, default None If the axis
>   is a MultiIndex (hierarchical), group by a particular level or levels

```
for count, sdf in df.groupby(level=0):
    values, bin_edges = np.histogram(sdf.loc[count, 'vel_x'])
```

**UPDATE**

Since you think the way `mean(level=level)` works is better, you can also try this way which is inspired by `mean` [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/generic.py#L5338-L5345):

```
df['vel_x'].groupby(level=0).aggregate(np.histogram)
```

Comment: Thanks @Yohanes. I have also done the loop that way, but I would like to avoid the loop since that is fairly slow when your dataframe is very large.

Comment: How can you calculate histogram without iterating all the data?

Comment: There is a pandas function df['Vel_x'].mean(level=0) which efficiently calculates the mean. I was wondering if there was something similar you could do for histogram.

Comment: If you follow the source link in the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html), you will see that `mean(level=level)` will eventually call [_agg_by_level](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/generic.py#L5338-L5345) which is using `groupby`. So I believe it's basically doing loop as well. But if you think following what `mean` does is better, you can try another alternative which is inspired by `mean` internal implementation (answer updated)

Comment: Thanks Yohanes! Your edit was exactly what I was looking for. I timed the difference between the methods using %%timeit in jupyter notebook with 1000 indices: Loop-> 1 loop, best of 3: 1.52 s per loop. Using aggregate-> 1 loop, best of 3: 267 ms per loop. That's quite a speedup!